# BaKoMaTeX Activation

Tags: bakoma

Do we have any chance to work the BaKoMaTeX purchased version as worked before the site went down?

Now I am facing an issue in installing the purchased version on a new machine. Since the activation is looking for the BaKoMaTeX site approval that is dead now.

Looking for a solution to install the purchased version and work with BaKoMaTeX as before the site went down.